# How to plot a function with matching x and y dimensions? ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1000,) and (1,)

Tags: python, function, plot, scipy, valueerror

Im trying to plot my function against n which is an array of 1000 values, my function consists of n as a variable as well as k which ive also set as an array of 1000. But when I go to plot it, my function only returns 1 value.

How do I make my function 'd' return the same number of values as the array so it can be plotted?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import jv
from scipy.special import yv
from scipy.special import yn
from scipy.special import jn

n = np.arange(0,1,0.001)
k = np.arange(0,100,0.1)
ni = 10**(-4)
A = 1
B = 0

def C1(k):
        return (np.sqrt(np.pi/2)*1/np.sqrt(k))*(((-5/2)*ni**.       (-7/2)*yv(5/2,k*ni)+1/2*ni**(-7/2)*yv(3/2,k*ni)-1/2*ni**(-5/2)*yv(7/2,k*ni))*A-ni**. (-5/2)*yv(5/2,k*ni)*B)/1/2*ni**(-5)*(jv(5/2,k*ni)*yv(3/2,k*ni)-  jv(5/2,k*ni)*yv(7/2,k*ni)+jv(3/2,k*ni)*yv(5/2,k*ni)-jv(7/2,k*ni)*yv(5/2,k*ni))

def C2(k):
    return (np.sqrt(np.pi/2)*1/np.sqrt(k))*(ni**jv(5/2,k*ni)*B-(-5/2*ni**(-7/2)*jv(5/2,k*ni)+1/2*ni**(-5/2)*jv(3/2,k*ni)-1/2*ni**(-5/2)*jv(7/2,k*ni))*A)/1/2*ni**(-5)*(jv(5/2,k*ni)*yv(3/2,k*ni)-jv(5/2,k*ni)*yv(7/2,k*ni)+jv(3/2,k*ni)*yv(5/2,k*ni)-jv(7/2,k*ni)*yv(5/2,k*ni))

def d(k,n):
        return C1*jn(2,k*n)/n**(5/2)


plt.plot(n,d)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider the code carefully - where it says `plt.plot(n,d)`, what do you expect that to mean? In particular, what kind of thing is `d`? A function, right? Did you intend to *call* the function? To call the function, arguments are required, yes? What should be passed? We don't generally help with debugging until after you have made your own attempt and come to a *specific question* that you can't answer yourself. You may find https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ helpful.

Comment: Hi, its means to plot n against d (I actually mean the other way around oops!). Yes d is a function which I want to plot with the arguments k and n. I just don't understand why its returning a single value for d when both k and n have 1000 values? Unless im missing something to make that happen. What do you mean by passed? Thanks :)

Comment: "d is a function which I want to plot with the arguments k and n." No; you do not want to plot a function - you want to plot the *results that are computed* by that function. Just like how, if you go to a restaurant and order some food, you cannot eat the words that you used to place the order. And in order to plot those results, they have to be computed, which happens when you *call* the function. Just like how you cannot actually place the order by thinking about what you want - you have to speak it.

Comment: If you do not understand what "calling a function" means, or what "passing arguments" means, I advise you to follow a tutorial, or to use a search engine to look it up. It's important to understand basic terminology so that you can ask clear questions that are properly understood, and so that you can *think* clearly about problems and become better at solving them.

Comment: I just want my function to return a value for each value of k and n in those arrays, so that I can plot them against n.

Comment: I understand calling a function I'm just not familiar with the terminology, I will read up on it now

Comment: Note that `n` and `k` can have different numbers of elements. If you want to have a result that does not depend on the floating-point representation of the increment, use `n=linspace(0,1,1000+1)` and `k=100*n`.